# What tcl command returns last evaluated command?

Tags: c, tcl, history

What tcl command returns last evaluated command? I think it should have something like bash history.

I have tried this, but it prints empty string.

```
set aaa bbb
puts [history info]
```

I have c++ program which create Tcl Interpreter and evaluates commands using it. In a specific moment I need to know what is last evaluated command. Is it possible using Tcl or C interfaces?

```
set a bbb
set b ccc
puts eee
set hh [history redo 1]
```

Now am getting error

```
event "1" hasn't occured yet
    while executing
"HistIndex $event"
    (procedure "tcl::HistRedo" line 6)
    invoked from within
"tcl::HistRedo [lindex $args 1]"
    (procedure "history" line 109)
    invoked from within
"history redo 1"
    invoked from within
"set hh [history redo 1]"
    (file "./a.itcl" line 17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review and manipulation of previously entered commands is available in tclsh using the [history](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/history.htm) command. This lets you review the previous command list and redo events.

In an interactive tclsh, there is also a `!!` or `!N` shortcut to `history redo N` to redo the last entered command or redo command N (where N is the event number).

It is not bound to up-arrow or ctrl-p or anything normal though. For that, you probably want some wrapper like rlwrap or `socat READLINE` to give readline-style line editing. If you have an X Windows session, then [tkcon](http://tkcon.sourceforge.net/) is more use and provides reasonable command line editing. On Windows, the tclsh gets to use the builting line editing from the cmd.exe prompt - including use of uparrow to get to previous commands.

In my test session:

```
% info pa
8.5.13
% history z
bad option "z": must be add, change, clear, event, info, keep, nextid, or redo
% history info
     1  info pa
     2  history z
     3  history info
% history redo 1
8.5.13
% exit
```

**Followup**

Additional comments from the original poster state that the code is not running in a standard tclsh interpreter. The history functionality is implemented in generic/tclHistory.c and the library/history.tcl library script. As noted in the C file header comment:

> This module and the Tcl library file history.tcl together implement
>    Tcl command history. Tcl_RecordAndEval(Obj) can be called to record
>    commands ("events") before they are executed. Commands defined in
>    history.tcl may be used to perform history substitutions.

so we can deduce that the custom interpreter must use the `Tcl_RecordAndEval` API call when evaluating commands that we want entered into the history. Presumably the current custom implementation is just using Tcl_Eval or one of the related functions.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am not using tclsh. I have interpreter which evaluates tcl commands. In some moment I need to know what is last evaluated command. Can you please explain why in the code of question, it doesn't print anything?

Comment: @Ashot Maybe try `puts [history redo 1]`? You should still be able store it in a variable using something similar to `set a [history redo 1]`

Comment: @Ashot You need to have something before running `history redo 1`; otherwise there's nothing to redo =P

Comment: @Jerry Of course I have run a command before history command. Please see updated question

Comment: @Ashot Hmm, I'm not sure. Maybe it's because I'm using the shell as intermediate? Try using `history add {command}` though it might not be practical if you have a lot to do =/

Comment: **tl;dr:** Use `Tcl_RecordAndEval` instead of `Tcl_Eval` from your custom interactive loop to integrate with Tcl's `history` mechanism.